# Meaning of the adverb "definitionally" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs

It was in [Crash Course World History](https://youtu.be/vfe-eNq-Qyg). It is at 3 minute and 44 second. Here it goes:

> It also lends itselve fairly well to herding, and since nomads are **definitionally** good at moving around, they are also good at moving stuff from point A to point B, which makes them good traders.

It seems to me that *definitionally* means *very*, but I am not sure if it does mean *very*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [normal collocation](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=definitionally%2Cby%20definition&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdefinitionally%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cby%20definition%3B%2Cc0) is **by definition**.  It is *an essential trait* of nomads that they are 'good at moving around'. That is what a nomad is, someone who moves around.

P.S. If you visit that Ngram link you'll see the sort of texts where "definitionally" appears.